# Why stream().map() can accept parameters like map(Student::getName)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

This is the `student` class definition.

```java
public class Student {
    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

The `map` function should accept like a `Function` interface

```java
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
```

That means the parameters should be like that

```java
int func(int a){
    return b;
}
```

We need to make sure have one method parameter.
So why `getName()` can work? 
The method actually change to `getName(Student this)`?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Could you actually include the code you want to use?  A [mcve] would help a lot here.  Include both broken (your question) and working code if possible.

Comment: The equivalent lambda expression would be `map(student -> student.getName())`.

Comment: "The method actually change to getName(Student this)?" Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By declaring the lambda/method reference as parameter, it should become obvious:

```
Function<Student, String> getNameFunction = student -> student.getName();
Function<Student, String> getNameMethodReference = Student::getName;
```

`Student` is the parameter to the `Function` and `String` is the returned type.

Hence, it matches the `map()` declaration:

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
```

And can be used like this:

```
Stream.of(new Student("")).map(Student::getName);
```

or without method reference:

```
Stream.of(new Student("")).map(student -> student.getName());
```

Or you can even use the declared `Function` variables:

```
Stream.of(new Student("")).map(getNameFunction);
Stream.of(new Student("")).map(getNameMethodReference);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. "Student::getName" is equivalent to "student -> student.getName()". I got it.